# Send Notification when Document is Created using Cloud Function

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-notifications

I'm using Firebase and Firestore as database

I want to push a new notification when a document is created at the user notification collection.

It should be something like this,

```
  const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

// // Create and Deploy Your First Cloud Functions
// // https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/write-firebase-functions
//
// exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
//  response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
// });

exports.sendNotificationToTopic = functions.firestore.document('notification/{notificationId}').onWrite(async  (event) => {

  var message ={
      notification: {
          title: "This is Title",
          body: "This is the Body",
          user: "fA0eLup_TUKVzdBkQbd3Qb:APA91bHuSuZOjdJgXn6xBndhQQkfnzm1pdLl9x3B2FZUYcYQULVPJFRbERezPuLoXD4QCUU2yalLUvgRfEas4B0sKAcwOkcmGkudLFvQWqTT7uhG21pKffTNTz5GvWKcD2-hKkfPq9Gq"

      },

      "token": user


  };

  let response=await admin.messaging().send(message);
  console.log(response);

});
```

Yes I'm using Cloud Function

And when I create a document in notification collection I didn't get notification 
 [image: this is my DB structure]

And I got some error in Cloud function log

```
sendNotificationToTopic 
Error: Exactly one of topic, token or condition is required at FirebaseMessagingError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (/srv/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:42:28) at FirebaseMessagingError.PrefixedFirebaseError [as constructor] (/srv/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:88:28) at new FirebaseMessagingError (/srv/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:254:16) at Object.validateMessage (/srv/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/messaging/messaging-types.js:46:15) at Messaging.send (/srv/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/messaging/messaging.js:207:27) at exports.sendNotificationToTopic.functions.firestore.document.onWrite (/srv/index.js:22:40) at cloudFunction (/srv/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:131:23) at /worker/worker.js:825:24 at <anonymous> at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a token to your var message variable.

`{
    "notification": {
        title: "This is Title",
        body: "This is the Body",
    },
    "token": user_info.device_id
}`

You can get the token from Tools --> Firebase --> Cloud Messaging --> Step 4 Firebase cloud messaging step 4 implementation explains it briefly.

[image]

Comment: how can i generate the token ?

Comment: i generated token and add in my file but got error                           
    ReferenceError: user is not defined
    at exports.sendNotificationToTopic.functions.firestore.document.onWrite (/srv/index.js:22:16)
    at cloudFunction (/srv/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:131:23)
    at /worker/worker.js:825:24
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)